# Oracle DataModeler problem initializing the JavaFX runtime

Tags: java, sql, linux, oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm trying to install Oracle DataModeler and I have a few problems so I'm going to put every step I made so the problem can be understood easier.

First my os is:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Parrot GNU/Linux 4.5"
NAME="Parrot GNU/Linux"
ID=parrot
ID_LIKE=debian
VERSION="4.5"
VERSION_ID="4.5"
HOME_URL="https://www.parrotsec.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://community.parrotsec.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://dev.parrotsec.org/"
```

**Now the installation:**

I downloaded the rpm package and installed using alien:

```
sudo alien --scripts  datamodeler-18.4.0.339.1532-1.noarch.rpm
```

And then I installed the *.deb package with:

```
sudo dpkg -i datamodeler-18.4.0.339.1532-1.noarch.deb
```

Now my problem is here. When I start the datamodeler via terminal it says something like '*set your java path*' so the fist thing I do is to look my jdk version and the one that I have installed is:

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.3+1-Debian-1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+1-Debian-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And with that version it doesn't simply work so I installed the jdk 8 version using synaptic and [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b61mD.png) are the packages that I installed.

So far so good until i run the program and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVASw.png) is what happens..

Here is the error:

```
Problem initializing the JavaFX runtime. This feature requires JavaFX.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.javafx.ui.JFXPanelFactory.createJFXPanelImpl(JFXPanelFactory.java:58)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.javafx.ui.JFXPanelFactory.createJFXPanel(JFXPanelFactory.java:34)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.startpage.StartPageViewer.createGUIComponent(StartPageViewer.java:179)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.startpage.StartPageViewer.getEditorContent(StartPageViewer.java:136)
    at oracle.ide.editor.AsynchronousEditor$2.run(AsynchronousEditor.java:345)
    at oracle.ide.editor.AsynchronousEditor$5.run(AsynchronousEditor.java:555)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel cannot be found by oracle.sqldeveloper_18.4.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.NetbinoxLoader.loadClass(NetbinoxLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

And the last thing I tried is to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install libjavafxsvg-java
```

But no changes and I don't know what to do next. My teachers won't help me out because they say that '*they do not know how to install it on linux'*.. 
So please I need someone who can save my day I have a work due this friday and I need this program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Okey I found the solution!

It was really simple I only had to download [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) jdk version and then unzip it where all the others jdk version are which is:

> /usr/lib/jvm/

And just add the following line at the conf file in .data_modeler/1.0.0.0.0/product.conf

```
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_201
```